# Vue Unit Testing: Using Functions imported Incorrectly into a Component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to retrofit unit testing into an old Vue app that we've developed. The one gotcha that's been set by my senior is that I cannot change any of the code in the actual app (this is causing too much headache for me).

Now, I'm trying to test if a method is activated when a user clicks a button:

```
import { mount, shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import AccountCreation from '@/components/.../AccountCreation.vue';
import createStoreConfig from '@/store/create-store-config';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

const storeConfig = createStoreConfig();
const store = new Vuex.Store(storeConfig);
store.state.selectedMemberType = 'writer';

describe('Account Creation', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(AccountCreation, {
    methods: {
    },
    store,
    localVue,
  });
  it('should return a writer argument when the validate username button is clicked', () => {
      let ga = () => {console.log('test')}
      const button = wrapper.find('#accountCreation .col-xl-5 .card span ').trigger('click')
  })
});
```

I know there's no `expect` in this test.
And the actual method looks like this. I know the method is being triggered, but `mocha`/`chai` throws an error before it can set a success.

I can't share the actual code, but basically it will do something like this:

```
validateUsername(fieldName) {
  ga('send', 'event', 'page' 'action' 'error')
}
```

There's more to the code, but none of it is run through since `ga` will throw a `ReferenceError` when run. Google Analytics was weirdly imported in `main.js`, so I can't stub it in the normal `sinon` or `mocha` way.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock `ga` via the `global` object (i.e., set `global.ga`):

```
it('should return a writer argument when the validate username button is clicked', () => {
  global.ga = () => {console.log('test')}
  const button = wrapper.find('#accountCreation .col-xl-5 .card span ').trigger('click')
})
```

Note this `global.ga` modification is persistent for each test in the file and not across files.